# momentjs aws-lambda wrong timezone at +12:00

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, momentjs, aws-cloudformation

I have this following node js code:

```
let pureDate = new Date('2022-12-22T00:00:00.000Z')
console.log(pureDate)
let formatted1 = moment(pureDate).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:00:00+hh:mm')
console.log(formatted1)
let formatted2 = moment.utc(pureDate).local().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:00:00+hh:mm')
console.log(formatted2)
```

When I run it at my Windows 10 local machine (+07:00), it print to console:

```
2022-12-22T00:00:00.000Z
2022-12-22T07:00:00+07:00
2022-12-22T07:00:00+07:00
```

Now I change timezone to +12:00 and rerun the code, it print:

```
2022-12-22T00:00:00.000Z
2022-12-22T12:00:00+12:00
2022-12-22T12:00:00+12:00
```

Everything were fine

Now I deploy it to aws lambda using cloudformation:

```
Resources:
  timerHandler:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: src.timerHandler
      Runtime: nodejs16.x
      Environment:
        Variables:
          NODE_ENV: lc
      Timeout: 100
      Events:
        ScheduledEvent:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Schedule: "rate(15 minutes)"
```

After sometime, I access the log and see (please scroll to right-end):

```
2022-12-22T22:47:04.451+07:00   2022-12-22T15:47:04.451Z e55ee401-87fd-4614-a7c6-971973ccccc6 INFO pureDate: 2022-12-22T00:00:00.000Z

2022-12-22T22:47:04.451+07:00   2022-12-22T15:47:04.451Z e55ee401-87fd-4614-a7c6-971973ccccc6 INFO formatted1: 2022-12-22T00:00:00+12:00

2022-12-22T22:47:04.451+07:00   2022-12-22T15:47:04.451Z e55ee401-87fd-4614-a7c6-971973ccccc6 INFO formatted2: 2022-12-22T00:00:00+12:00
```

The time 00:00:00 is correct, but the zone +12:00 is not.
I would expect the formatted should be 2022-12-22T12:00:00+12:00 or 2022-12-22T00:00:00+00:00

Is that the problem of momentjs, or my code, or lambda? How can I fix it?

moment version: "^2.29.4"

=============================================================================

UPDATE:

This is zone information of the lambda execution:

```
2022-12-22T23:46:32.052+07:00   2022-12-22T16:46:32.052Z f1d04019-44e7-463a-af1d-faf2a5043887 INFO zone_name: Africa/Abidjan

2022-12-22T23:46:32.052+07:00   2022-12-22T16:46:32.052Z f1d04019-44e7-463a-af1d-faf2a5043887 INFO timezone: GMT
```

=============================================================================

UPDATE:

Also tried to set TZ variable to UTC but the same issue

Comment: Please do not post "Update" sections to questions - just edit the whole question to be "updated" to help us understand the problem in one reading.

Comment: And why do you expect `+12:00`? Lambda runs on UTC, so even `.local()` will return UTC. You're not providing a timezone anywhere.

Comment: `or at least 2022-12-22T00:00:00+00:00` this is my expectation. The time 00:00:00+00:00 is correct, otherwise 12:00:00+12:00 is still acceptable, but not 00:00:00+12:00. Beside, the lambda is running at Africa/Abidjan, please read my update